# Sample create subscription request using graphServiceclient

Tags: c#, outlook-restapi

Looking for a c# example of creating a subscrption using  graphServiceclient

this article shows the Rest Endpoings ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/webhooks) , but I want to use graphServiceclient instead

This example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/dotnet-tutorial) shows how to read a mailbox - i want to subscribe to notifications of changes in the mailbox.
Thanks, Peter

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example, including a receiver for those WebHooks....

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-apponlytoken-webhooks-sample